# Session Objects in Global.asax File

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am working on a Web Application and i want that when the user logged In the UserID should be stored in Session. I know how to create Session.

```
Session["UserID"] = myvalue;
```

But i want that to be used on everypage. so i dont want to write code or check for session availability on every page. will Global.asax file help me ?

If i write session in `Session_Start()` then will that be accessible on all pages ? and if expired the return to login page.

Just require proper guidance. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use [ASP.NET Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I am already using Membership and Roles. This is just for example. Actually am taking Financial Year in session.

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest creating a basepage that is inherited by every page but the login. this way you are only creating the session variable code on one page but that code is accessible by any page that inherits it.

edit with small example:

when your user is authenticated you need to set your session variable

currently your pages probably look something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

what you need to do is create a separate class file, basepage.cs for example that looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class basepage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected int GetItem()
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(Session["myvalue"]);
        }
    }
}
```

and then your original page would look more like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : basepage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int whatINeed = GetItem();
        }
    }
}
```

as you see instead of your page inheriting the `System.Web.UI.Page` it is inheriting the basepage (which in turn inherits `System.Web.UI.Page`).

Comment: give me a moment while i cook one up

Comment: Thanks so much for this wonderful example peroija. This is correct but i have one problem that i want to overcome with. This will give me the data. but what if the session is expired ? i guess when the user has fill detail on full page, then when the user click on Submit, and when i try to access the session, it is expired.

Comment: Then he is redirected to login and again he has to fill the form. so i want to overcome this problem. can you suggest me something good for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I used to write as a separate class to handle session and return it as a property. I can write all the condition in the class.

Comment: my prob is like i am using session values in my database tables , Like Insert, Select etc. so when ever i am firing that events then i have to check weather session is valid or not. i want some thing globally that any event fires, session should be checked..

Comment: I use to call the SessionHandler method in page load and get the values of the session as properties.